# ffmpeg batch retains old filetype in name

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, filenames

I'm using the following `ffmpeg` script to convert all .mp4 files in the folder to .webm.

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c:v libvpx -crf 4 -b:v 3M -c:a libvorbis "%%A.webm"
```

I am trying to make it go from `"xxx.mp4"` to `"xxx.webm"`

However when I run the script the file name goes from `"xxx.mp4"` to `"xxx.mp4.webm"`

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Does windows explorer show extensions by default? Turning that off while running the script may help. Alternatively, you could rename all of them after ffmpeg is done with them.

Comment: Yes I had file extensions visible.  When turning it off i had the same result, a webm file with the name "xxx.mp4". I'd like to have the output name be correct after conversion if possible, but if not I suppose I'll just have to rename them all afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%%~nA.webm` to select the name-part of the filename.

see `for /?` from the prompt or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To recursively convert in webm all the mp4 video files in nested folders, you can try this command:

```
find '~/Video/' -iname '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'D=$(dirname "{}"); B=$(basename "{}"); mkdir "$D/webm/"; ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v libvpx -crf 4 -b:v 3M -c:a libvorbis "$D/webm/${B%.*}.webm"' \;
```

It will create a folder named "webm" inside the one with mp4 video files and, inside the "webm" folder, it will save relative webm files, without keeping the old file extension in the name.